# RDLC reports not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services

My rdlc reports are not working when I deploy my windows application. Please help.
I tried changing build action content, but to no avail.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Does it work in design mode?

Comment: Yes, says it cant find my oledb database but it is there. yes it works in design mode

Comment: I got this working. Thanks.